# Watching events with truffle test

Tags: truffle, events, testing

Given following solidity code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract Foo {

    event FooInc(uint256 _a);
    uint256 a;

    constructor() public {
        a = 42;
    }

    function inc() public returns(bool) {
        a += 1;
        emit FooInc(a);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and following test javascript code:

```
let Foo = artifacts.require('Foo');

contract("foocontract", async accounts => {
    it("testing inc", async (done) => {
        let foo = await Foo.deployed();
        foo.allEvents().on('data', function(e) {
            console.log('allevents', e);
            done();
        });
        foo.inc().then(r => {
            console.log('done', r);         
            foo.getPastEvents('allEvents', undefined, (e, l) => {
                console.log("pastevents", e, l);
                done();
            });

        });
    });
});
```

The receipt from the `foo.inc()` promise gets logged. Neither of the event listener accessors for the contract events fire, although the receipt object shows the event was triggered.

```
$ truffle test
Using network 'test'.


Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/Foo.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol
> Artifacts written to /tmp/test-2020127-266345-9s8aje.7jzss
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang



  Contract: foocontract
done {
  tx: '0x158109501fa0cecffa6c7887d05c255cb5e76002c25881f5e684ab199a75cdff',
  receipt: {
    transactionHash: '0x158109501fa0cecffa6c7887d05c255cb5e76002c25881f5e684ab199a75cdff',
    transactionIndex: 0,
    blockHash: '0x55e2fce5a0257fad6d851ba35e03885509f98a6641e3e92a146e2fbaad9e3a18',
    blockNumber: 5,
    from: '0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57',
    to: '0x345ca3e014aaf5dca488057592ee47305d9b3e10',
    gasUsed: 28961,
    cumulativeGasUsed: 28961,
    contractAddress: null,
    logs: [ [Object] ],
    status: true,
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000',
    rawLogs: [ [Object] ]
  },
  logs: [
    {
      logIndex: 0,
      transactionIndex: 0,
      transactionHash: '0x158109501fa0cecffa6c7887d05c255cb5e76002c25881f5e684ab199a75cdff',
      blockHash: '0x55e2fce5a0257fad6d851ba35e03885509f98a6641e3e92a146e2fbaad9e3a18',
      blockNumber: 5,
      address: '0x345cA3e014Aaf5dcA488057592ee47305D9B3e10',
      type: 'mined',
      id: 'log_8dfd46f8',
      event: 'FooInc',
      args: [Result]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using `truffle@v5.1.14` and the docs for it suggest that it should merely be a matter of listening for javascript events `data` and `error`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me on Truffle v4.1.16:

```
const Foo = artifacts.require('Foo');

contract("foocontract", async accounts => {
    it("testing inc", async (done) => {
        const foo = await Foo.deployed();
        const receipt = await foo.inc();
        printLogs("receipt", receipt.logs);
        foo.allEvents().get(function(error, logs) {
            assert.equal(error, null);
            printLogs("listened", logs);
        });
    });
});

function printLogs(title, logs) {
    for (let i = 0; i < logs.length; i++) {
        console.log();
        console.log(`${title} event #${i + 1}:`);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(logs[i], null, 4));
    }
}
```

You may want to try something similar on your version of Truffle.

Keep in mind that Truffle v4.x relies on web3.js v0.x, while Truffle v5.x relies on web3.js v1.x.

So there might be a few differences in how events are listened to.

Comment: `foo.allEvents()` gives me an `EventEmitter` but it does not have `get()` :/

Comment: @lash: Like I said, "You may want to try something **similar** on your version of Truffle. I don't have Truffle 5.x installed, so check the docs to see how to use that `EventEmitter` (or even print this object in order to see what methods it exposes).

Comment: yeah, I appreciate the hint. Just wanted to document here for others looking to provide help that `get()` fails. Incidentally, so does `addEventListener()`. `on()` compiles, but produces nothing, like explained above. ... I'm assuming `EventEmitter` is this: https://nodejs.org/docs/v13.7.0/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter

Comment: @lash: It's actually [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events-return) - web3.js docs, which I personally find to be easier than Truffle docs (and I'm pretty sure that your link to NodeJS docs is irrelevant in this context). Have a look around there, you may find several functions that will answer your requirements (for example, `getPastEvents` if you scroll down a bit).

Comment: that would be a very cheeky overload by `web3` if the `EventEmitter` class would totally change its interface. According to the docs the web3 version should still support `.on`. Meanwhile I followed up on your hint for `getPastEvents()` which did not yield any better results, and I've updated the question with code using that aswell.

Answer (score 2):

With truffle 5, solc 0.7

```js
const CrowdFundingWithDeadline = artifacts.require("TestCrowdFundingWithDeadline");

contract('CrowdFundingWithDeadline' , async accounts => {
    let contract;
    let account = accounts[0];
    let beneficiary = accounts[1];
    const ONE_ETH = 1000000000000000000;
    const Ongoing_State = 0;
    const Faild_State = 1;
    const Succeeded_State = 2;
    const Paidout_State = 3;

    beforeEach(async function () {
        contract = await CrowdFundingWithDeadline.new(
            'funding',
            1,
            10,
            beneficiary,
            {
                from: account,
                gas: 2000000
            }
        );
    });
    
    it('event is emitted', async function () {
        await contract.setCurrentTime(601);
        let res = await contract.finishCrowdFunding();
        let eventName = res.logs[0].event;
        let eventRes = res.logs[0].args;
        expect(Number.parseInt(eventRes.totalCollected)).to.equal(0);
        expect(eventRes.succeeded).to.equal(false);
    });
});
```